# How can I find out the windows server 2008 R2 edition?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

How can I find out the windows server 2008 R2 edition ?

Comment: Find out what ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
winver
```

This will pop up a Window with the Edition name (e.g Windows Server 2008 R2 etc) Version number (6.1 for W2K8 R2), Build Number and some licensing info.

```
ver
```

Will give you the version number in the format `6.1.BuildNo` from a CMD shell. Windows 7 and 2008R2 both report as version 6.1.x.

Answer (score 0):

see this answer: [How to detect Windows Server 2003/2008 Release (R1 or R2) programatically?](https://serverfault.com/questions/189655/how-to-detect-windows-server-2003-2008-release-r1-or-r2-programatically/189664#189664)

Answer (score 0):

Download it? Here http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/default.aspx or via MSDN.com